# Is it okay to normalize by row after running a PCA?

Tags: scikit-learn, normalization, pca

I have a dataset of 50K rows and 26 features. I'm normalizing the columns using sklearn's StandardScaler (each column has 0 mean and 1 standard deviation), then running a PCA to reduce the featureset to ~90% of the original variance. I'm then normalizing the rows, before I run sklearn's KMeans algorithm.

Is there any reason I shouldn't be normalizing the rows after running a PCA? If there is, would normalizing the rows before the PCA cause any issues - should this be done before or after normalizing the columns?

The reason for normalizing the rows is to remove the 'magnitude' or 'skill level' from each row, and instead, look at the relationship between the respective PCA-reduced features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very dependent on the data.  Since I don't know what these "skill level" numbers might have for data shape, I'm hesitant to give a direct answer.  For instance, is it reasonable to have some rows with several normalized scores outside the [-1, 1] range, while others have values of small magnitude?  It sounds like this is the case you're trying to address.

I worry that you'll have a lot of rows with several values in the 1-2 range (either + or -), but some rows with perhaps a single +1 value with the rest of the items near 0.  When you normalize a "one-hot" row, you'll get that one value expanded larger than 10.  Do you want it clustered as an outlier, or included in the central region of the space?  Is someone with a single more-than-mediocre trait an *outlier* for this data?

There's nothing wrong with re-normalizing after a PCA.  However, if you normalize both before and after, you won't get much change, since you kept a large majority of the data, removing only those that seem redundant.

Comment: Thanks for your comments on this. Perhaps, centering the mean of each row at 0, but not doing anything with the standard deviation would lead to less manufactured outliers. I'm going to try a few different approaches and see what the results show. Thanks for helping me think through the issue.

Comment: Glad to be of help.  Please let me know what works; I'd like to learn from this, too.

Comment: So I tried normalizing rows (mean=0, stdev=1), centering rows (mean=0, stdev unchanged), and not normalizing rows. Centering rows by far produced the most meaningful results. There were 11 groups in my dataset, based on experience levels, and the distance to the nearest centroid by group was the metric of interest. I calculated Welch's T-Tests of distances to nearest centroid between each respective group. One (somewhat hacky) evaluation metric was to sum the absolute values of all such TTests. The centered data tstat absolute val sum was ~2,100, unchanged data was ~1400, normed data was ~380.

Comment: Thanks for the report; quite interesting results.  Those sum-abs figures are telling.  Are they corrected for the normalization (not) used?  It's not fair to complain that one is 6x another if you've simply divided all the ranges by 6.  :-)