# KMeans evaluation metric not converging. Is this normal behavior or no?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, scikit-learn, k-means, evaluation

I'm working on a problem that necessitates running KMeans separately on ~125 different datasets. Therefore, I'm looking to mathematically calculate the 'optimal' K for each respective dataset. However, the evaluation metric continues decreasing with higher K values.

For a sample dataset, there are 50K rows and 8 columns. Using sklearn's [calinski-harabaz score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.calinski_harabaz_score.html#sklearn.metrics.calinski_harabaz_score), I'm iterating through different K values to find the optimum / minimum score. However, my code reached k=5,600 and the calinski-harabaz score was still decreasing!

Something weird seems to be happening. Does the metric not work well? Could my data be flawed (see my [question about normalizing rows after PCA)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41508161/is-it-okay-to-normalize-by-row-after-running-a-pca) Is there another/better way to mathematically converge on the 'optimal' K? Or should I force myself to manually pick a constant K across all datasets?

Any additional perspectives would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SUMMARY**

The metric decreases with each increase of **K**; this strongly suggests that you do not have a natural clustering upon the data set.

**DISCUSSION**

CH scores depend on the ratio between intra- and inter-cluster densities.  For a relatively smooth distribution of points, each increase in **K** will give you clusters that are slightly more dense, with slightly lower density between them.  Try a lattice of points: vary the radius and do the computations by hand; you'll see how that works.  At the extreme end, **K** = **n**: each point is its own cluster, with infinite density, and 0 density between clusters.

**OTHER METRICS**

Perhaps the simplest metric is sum-of-squares, which is already part of the clustering computations.  Sum the squares of distances from the centroid, divide by **n-1** (n=cluster population), and then add/average those over all clusters.

I'm looking for a particular paper that discusses metrics for this very problem; if I can find the reference, I'll update this answer.

N.B. With any metric you choose (as with CH), a failure to find a local minimum suggests that the data really don't have a natural clustering.

**WHAT TO DO NEXT?**

Render your data in some form *you* can visualize.  If *you* see a natural clustering, look at the characteristics; how is it that you can see it, but the algebra (metrics) cannot?  Formulate a metric that highlights the differences you perceive.

I know, this is an effort similar to the problem you're trying to automate.  Welcome to research.  :-)

Comment: Indeed, there didn't appear to be a natural grouping in my dataset(s). The optimal K value was 1, actually. The max of the CH score was when K=2 (i.e. the minimum K tried) across the board, and when I forced K to =1, this produced the best results for my dataset(s). As I mentioned in another comment, I tried another method that found K based on when the 2nd derivative of BIC fell below a certain user-defined threshold. This produced meaningful results, too, but not as good as when K=1. Interesting...more to look into, but thanks a ton for helping me think through this!

Comment: Glad to be of help.  I'm chuckling at the results ... this is a data set that's playing games with your head.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know anything about the calinski-harabaz score but some score metrics will be monotone increasing/decreasing with respect to increasing K. For instance the mean squared error for linear regression will always decrease each time a new feature is added to the model so other scores that add penalties for increasing number of features have been developed.

There is a very good [answer here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52838/what-is-an-acceptable-value-of-the-calinski-harabasz-ch-criterion) that covers CH scores well. A simple method that generally works well for these monotone scoring metrics is to plot K vs the score and choose the K where the score is no longer improving 'much'. This is very subjective but can still give good results.

Comment: Thanks for this, Ted. In the link you shared - and on sklearn's site - it mentions that the 'best' CH score is actually the maximum (not the minimum, which is what I mistakenly assumed in my question above). That said, I did implement code that optimized the K value based on where it falls below a user-defined threshold for the 2nd derivative of the BIC score. This produced okay results, but the CH max was more effective on my dataset(s).

Answer (score 0):

The problem with my question is that the 'best' Calinski-Harabaz score is the maximum, whereas my question assumed the 'best' was the minimum. It is computed by analyzing the ratio of between-cluster dispersion vs. within-cluster dispersion, the former/numerator you want to maximize, the latter/denominator you want to minimize. As it turned out, in this dataset, the 'best' CH score was with 2 clusters (the minimum available for comparison). I actually ran with K=1, and this produced good results as well. As Prune suggested, there appears to be no natural grouping within the dataset.